# Are there GUI resources for gdal and ogr?

Tags: gdal, ogr, gui

For those who are new to the programming side of GIS, I feel that a lot of great tools and resources are inacessible. I am interested in GUI based wizards for handling geoprocessing with libraries like gdal and ogr. Any tips?

Comment: What is exactly the geoprocessing you want to do? Perhaps there are much better tools out there who can do the job (eg saga gis). Though they have some geoprocessing functionality, their main focus is data conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For ogr2ogr you can check [ogr2gui](http://www.ogr2gui.ca/en/index.php). Although this is a bit old one, according to the website:

> Through its graphical user interface, ogr2gui gives all the power of
>   ogr2ogr without worrying about its complex syntax. It brings speed,
>   efficiency and simplicity to its users.

Comment: org2gui [was forked](http://ogr2gui.ca/) and updated in 2014. It seems they only support windows, but the source is [available](https://github.com/zer0infinity/OGR2GUI).

Answer (score 10):

[QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/about-qgis.html) among several other options.

Comment: virtually all decent open source packages that deal with geospatial data access use GDAL (including ArcGIS). Anything specific you need?

Answer (score 4):

The GDAL FAQ at
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQGeneral#IsthereagraphicaluserinterfacetoGDALOGR
points to
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/SoftwareUsingGdal

Thats obviously a pretty large (and probably incomplete) list of things. If you can advise on what you need to do, perhaps someone can provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS has the GDAL and OGR libraries built in. Some of the raster tools in QGIS have batch options and the show you the syntax of the command for command line tools like FWTools. As a not, there are some differences between the executables in QGIS and FWTools.

Answer (score 2):

[WARNING: A gratuitous promotion of a product I am involved with]

We have been working on exactly this. We have developed an application that has an advanced GUI for GIS (and other) data transformations. This uses GDAL/OGR in the back end. Some information can be found at https://www.geoactive.it

Commercial use requires it to be purchased but we do have academic licenses available for free so if you want to use it for study ect message me and I will provide you with some more details.

This is in it early release stage so there are still some minor bugs ect so please be gentle with us.

Answer (score 1):

For those who may be interested, we have started to work on an open source utility, **Rasterix**.

It is a **cross-platform** utility (available for Windows, macOS and Linux) built with the **GDAL library** and the **Qt framework**. It can perform most of the tasks already implemented in various GDAL command line utilities, but using a friendly graphical user interface.

The source code and the pre-built binaries are hosted on github at https://github.com/mogasw/rasterix.

We will add more features in the future, but should you be interested in something in particular, let us know using github's issues.